# How to debug vscode extension installation in remote docker container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a docker container on a remote machine, which i access in vscode using the remote dev extension pack via ssh and container dev extension pack.

Installing extensions locally and remotely works ok, however the process get stuck on "installing" when i try it in remote container, for any extensions.

The remote computer is behind a proxy, however networks work fine in container since i can `apt install` packages and download from links.

I have tried looking in the output tab for `Extension Host` and `Extension Host (Remote)`, but I dont see anything standing out. The `toggle developer tools` command does show an error message in console when i click on the installation:

```
ERR Error while installing 'ms-python.python' extension in the remote server. aborted
```

And nothing else. I'm looking for a more detailed way of debugging vscode extensions installation in containers, where i can at least get an error code or something a bit more explicit, if someone has previous experience with that it would be of great help.